# MEAN application setup doesn't redirect routes to Angular application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am trying to setup a base for a MEAN application. I created the new project using Angular CLI, added Express.js, MongoDB modules to the application. In the `app.js` file I have the following configuration:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var path = require("path")
var app = express();

var conf = require('./config/conf');
var server = require('http').Server(app);

var mongoDB = require('./adapters/mongodb')
var mongoClient = new mongoDB(conf);

app.use(bodyParser());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,__setXHR_');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});

mongoClient.connect(function (dbconn) {
    app.dbconn = dbconn;
    app.conf = conf;
    console.log("************************************************************");
    console.log(new Date() + ' | CRUD Server Listening on ' + conf['web']['port']);
    console.log("************************************************************");
    server.listen(conf['web']['port']);
    var Routes = require('./routes/http-routes');
    new Routes(app);
});
```

I setup a hello world route for now and no changes done to the angular sources, which means I would land at the Angular default starting page. But I cant land at the page but instead a white screen page. However, I can access the routes using Postman. I do `ng build` and then `node app.js` to run the application. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show angular code for routing, and you should also look at the errors in the console when you get a blank page, also why do you put your routes into the database connection ? There's an Express way to handle routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Express way to handle routes

**First**

```
const router=express.Router();
```

**Then** let's suppose you have a file using only authentication routes

```
const authentication = require('./routes/authentication')(router);
```

**To conclude**, you only have to do :

```
app.use('/authentication', authentication);
```

This allows a better divison of your routes

You 'll use your routes this way

```
module.exports= (router)=>{

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
res.json(message:'Hello World');
});

return router;
```

To set angular routes you need the router module, for more details read the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Answer (score 1):

You serve only index.html from your Angular App. But you need also serve assets, css and javascript. Easiest would be something like this (but you need to adjust directory names:

```
app.use('/js', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js')));
app.use('/css', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/css')));
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/assets')));
```